# woocommerce_order_status_completed has no data

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I have created a webhook for woocommerce_order_status_completed, this hook is successfully triggered when an order is completed.

The problem is I do not get any data from the order completed other than its ID. the response shows as the following.

```
{"action":"woocommerce_order_status_completed","arg":1640}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a plugin with this code that solved the issue :

```
function set_resource_for_webhook_payload_by_webhook_id($target_webhook_id, 
$desired_resource) {


add_filter('woocommerce_webhook_resource', function($resource, $webhook_id) use 
($target_webhook_id, $desired_resource) {
if($webhook_id == $target_webhook_id) {
        return $desired_resource;
    }
    return $resource;
}, 10, 2);


add_filter('woocommerce_valid_webhook_events', function($valid_events) use ($target_webhook_id) {
    try {
        $topic = wc_get_webhook($target_webhook_id)->get_topic();

        list($resource, $event) = explode('.', $topic);

        if(!empty($event)) {
            $valid_events[] = $event;
        }

        return $valid_events;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $valid_events;
    }
}, 10);

}
//Replace number (3) bellow with your webhook ID:
add_action('init', function(){
set_resource_for_webhook_payload_by_webhook_id(3, 'order');
});
```

Hope it helps anyone.